# Compare caretPositionFromPoint, which is bigger?

Tags: javascript, dom

I get the `caretPositionFromPoint` for two elements:

```
var start = doc.caretPositionFromPoint(someX, someY);
var end = doc.caretPositionFromPoint(otherX, otherY);
```

How can I check whether start is later in the document than end?

Comment: What is `doc.caretPositionFromPoint`?

Comment: @Doorknob, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.caretPositionFromPoint

Comment: If they are part of different nodes, which I expect they will be then not easily. Why don't you just compare the X and Y positions, to work out which one is further down the page?

Comment: Because I need to pass the elements into a selectionrange. If the wrong element is put as the start it will make a selection from that element to the end of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by making a `Range` which has methods for this.

```
  var sr = document.createRange();
  sr.setStart(start.offsetNode, start.offset);
  sr.setEnd(start.offsetNode, start.offset);
  if (sr.comparePoint(end.offsetNode, end.offset) === -1) {
    // end is before start
  }
```